# Bad audit example question which should be removed

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I got a review (audit as it seemed later on) about [XCode 6 GM crashes when selecting the main storyboard or a xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787181/xcode-6-gm-crashes-when-selecting-the-main-storyboard-or-a-xib)

I choose to **leave the question closed**, which was seemingly the [wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5791709).

Personally, I am not a XCode expert but the question still seems to lack required information. But the question lacks the following:

- There are barely/not enough details provided, as it only shows some error message without providing details about the crash or things (storyboard, the specific xib, code, etc.) that influenced the crash.
- The actual question is whether anyone experiences the same problem. This sounds very vague, opinion based (especially due to the lack of details) to me.
  When looking at the answers (one is deleted), the people answering also do seem to respond vaguely, due to the vague question. (And they also seem to miss details to properly/fully answer the question).
- The used tags seem incorrect (although this did not directly influence my decision). As the question is not about iOS or Swift. The OP might have been running XCode on iOS while writing some Swift application, but they do not matter.

So, I still think this question should have been left closed. (but that might be due to my lack of experience with the subject). But, the question certainly does not seem suitable for auditing reviewers!

Therefore I propose that this question is not going to be used for auditing reviewers anymore (assuming there is some internal list containing such questions, from which this one can be deleted?).

Comment: -1 because there are plenty of "disputed review audit" questions on meta and most say the same exact thing.... audits are automatically generated based on a number of factors, and if you disagree with the audit then the best way to prevent it from being used as an audit again is to act on the post.  So if you voted to close it, then it would no longer be considered for a close or reopen audit.

Comment: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: @psubsee2003 you are right, it is discussed more often (my bad of not searching for them more thoroughly). When looking at these questions, it seems to be unclear to the reviewers what to do in these situations... Maybe the text that is shown as a result of a wrong audit needs to be made more clear and contain possible actions to prevent the question being used for audits in the future? As you explained in your comment.

Comment: @Veger Sounds like a possible feature request.  But I would disagree with the idea.  I don't think we necessarily want to encourage everyone to immediately vote to close and/or downvote just because they disagree with an audit.  For users that either "know" the guidelines or determined enough to come to meta to find out what to do, then the question is more likely to warrant the vote.  Plus it may give uninformed users hope that in doing so it would overturn the audit failure.

Comment: @psubsee2003 'the very ability to dispute review audit _["This audit is incorrect" button]_ can be rate-limited in addition to already established rate limits on review...' ([“STOP! Look and Listen” audit tricked me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156942/165773))